# Пример постановки двоеточия

Tags: двоеточие

Есть такое мероприятие в Москве для студенчества: называется "День тренингов".

Уместно ли здесь двоеточие (как бы уточнение мероприятия)? Предложение сложноподчиненное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там тире нужно. Для уточнения как раз тире используется (как минимум запятая).

Двоеточие - для перечисления, объяснения причин. Было бы два названия - двоеточие бы подошло ещё.

Answer (score 0):

***(1) Есть такое мероприятие в Москве для студенчества ―  "День тренингов".***

***(2) Есть такое мероприятие в Москве для студенчества, называется (оно)  "День тренингов".***

Вообще-то при объяснении знаков препинания **желательно определять вид грамматической конструкции.**

В предложении (1) это обособленное приложение в конце предложения, название мероприятия.

Предложение (2) бессоюзное сложное, второе предложение неполное, оно продолжает тему первой части. Причин для постановки тире или двоеточия нет.

Примеры:

...место это проклятое, **называется оно Чёрный Яр,** водятся в нём древние щуки, которой по двести, которой по триста лет. [А. Н. Толстой. На рыбной ловле (1923)]

Другое нововведение ― серьезное, и **называется оно « Народный университет».** [В. А. Каверин. Перед зеркалом (1965-1970)]

Comment: А может ли употребляться (2) в качестве приложения? Есть такое мероприятие - называется "День тренингов"

Comment: Не может. Приложение - это определение, выраженное существительным, а у Вас предложение.

Comment: Можно переделать в простое предложение с причастным оборотом: Есть такое мероприятие - называемое "Днём тренингов".  Такой приём может быть очень эффектным для чего-то пафосного. Например: Существует некий очень могущественный меч, называемый Экскалибуром.